# Transparent hierarchical data frames in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*Not sure about terminology.*

I have a JavaScript "object" with some data:

```
var parent = { foo: 42, bar: 2.71, baz: 3.14 };
```

I need to create another JavaScript object that will provide access to the parent object, while supporting local overrides for parent's entries:

```
var child = extend(parent, { foo: 1, quo: 2 });

child.bar = 3;
parent.qux = 4;

assert(parent.foo === 42);
assert(child.foo === 1);

assert(parent.bar === 2.71);
assert(child.bar === 3);

assert(parent.baz === 3.14);
assert(child.baz === 3.14);

assert(parent.quo === undefined);
assert(child.quo === 2);

assert(parent.qux === 4);
assert(child.qux === 4);

// NB: I don't care about iteration on these objects.
```

I need the solution to be as low-overhead as possible while being cross-browser enough. Copying parent values to the child is too much overhead.

That is, I'm looking for something akin to Lua [metatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) chains, but in JavaScript.

I was reading about `[[Prototype]]` chains. It looks like the way to go, but I did not figure out a lightweight way to use them here yet. (`__proto__`, as I understand it, is not cross-browser enough.)

Any clues?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `Object.create`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Care to add it as an answer to be accepted? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By dropping the initializer to the child object, I was able to come up with this (updated, thanks to @FelixKling):

```
var wrap = function(parent) 
{
  var child = function() { };
  child.prototype = parent;
  return new child();
}
```

Can it be improved further?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5Q4n/2/

Note that as suggested in comments, there is a JS function, doing almost what is needed: `Object.create`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: *"Can it be improved?"* You can remove all the constructor stuff. I don't see its purpose.